# Is there way to GC object in Flex even if there are objects binded to it?

Tags: apache-flex, garbage-collection

I'm wondering how to garbage collect a variable in Flex even if there are other objects binded to it.

Comment: Garbage collection usually tracks *objects* and object-reachability (variables can make objects reachable but are not [generally] objects themselves). If an object is strongly reachable, it can never be safely GC'ed. Not sure how object binding in Flex works, but the above still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a "weak reference" when binding, the object will be eligible for garbage collection.

Read more:
http://ted.onflash.org/2008/09/useweakreferencesboolean-false.php